# Should search results auto update when an auto-suggest option is clicked?

Tags: search, autocomplete

Google, Bing, Yahoo, Amazon, and Ebay implement auto suggest when a user types in the search field. Google automatically updates the list of search results when an auto suggest option is clicked. Should this be the standard? The other pages I listed require the user to click the search button to update the results. Which option is more user-friendly?

Comment: Which one requires more effort from the user?

Comment: @Jonathan that depends, do users prefer constantly changing results or on demand results?  Some users like me gets annoyed with the constant flashing/changing results, others prefer it.  More effort in terms of physical clicks or more effort in terms of cognition...

Comment: @ChairmanMeow I agree, but you could solve that by a slight delay so it doesn't update with every keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say auto-updating the results is the most friendly result. The user has already confirmed by clicking on the suggestion that they would like to run that search. Making them click once more is unnecessary work for the user.

It's not always true that the least number of click is the best. But for a simple process like this one, once the user tells you they want to search the suggested term, it should just happen.